# How to get data from API "PokeAPI"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I have React component :

```
import React from "react";
import { Pokemons } from "../Pokemons";

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pokemons: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20")
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ pokemons: Object.values(data) }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className="container content">
        <Pokemons pokemon={this.state.pokemons} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export { Main };
```

**The API I'm using is** ***[PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/)***

**My task is to display data about the first 20 Pokémon (which is what I'm trying to do in fetch() ). But I don't get exactly what I need:**

[Console information.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vINUk.png)

**That is, JSON with four elements comes in response, the one I need is in the last one ( 3: ):**

[Console information 2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBV3b.png)

**In addition, each of the twenty objects (Pokémon) has a name and a link: **

[Console Information 3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyEfr.png)

**From this I need only the name, the rest of the necessary information (type, height, sprite) are data on these links. Example data in the link:**

[Data from link.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEMJ9.png)

**In fact, the name of the pokemon is also in the data contained in these links.**

*I have never come across such an API structure before =(*

***Question - Help me get the name, type, sprite, height and weight of the Pokémon...***

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `Object.values(data)`
replace it with `data.results`

data contains the first layer of data, which includes count, next, results, etc...
you are interested in the results object, that contains the name, type, etc...

by doing data.results, you push the 20 pokemon objects to your state, then you can either

1. iterate over the array of objects and render `<Pokemon />` for each pokemon
   or
2. send the entire pokemon array to `<Pokemon />` component and do that within the component itself.

example:

1. ````
    return (
      <main className="container content">
      {this.state.pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
        <Pokemons pokemon={pokemon} />)}
      </main>
    );```
   ````
2. ````
    return (
      <main className="container content">
        <Pokemons pokemons={this.state.pokemons} />
      </main>
    );```
   ````

`// Pokemons Component accepts pokemon array, and iterate it`

Comment: But then I will just get a name and a link in each <Pokemon> component, and I need to take a few more data (type, sprite, height, weight) by the link that is contained in each element (each link is a new request to the API)

Comment: @Yevhenii, Since you rely on the data from the API, you really only have two choices:

1)make this request above in my example, and add an onClcik event with the link provided by the API, which will trigger another request to get the full pokemon details.

2) use GraphQL API, it's in beta but it lets you basically make one query that gets all the data you want at once. you can find more details [here](https://pokeapi.co/docs/graphql) and you can find real-world examples by pokemon's team [here](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/blob/master/graphql/examples/pokemon_stats.gql)